# es gibt ... hinweg

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of **hinweg** in this context:

> Im Digitalrat gibt es eine große Offenheit über Parteigrenzen hinweg

I have checked in Duden but still no idea why it is used at the end of the sentence. Is it simply to double highlight the existence of *Digitalrat* somehow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The adverb *hinweg* pairs with the preposition *über* to a standing expression meaning "crossing something". The usage of this expression is marked as elevated in some dictionaries.

Your sentence translates along the lines of

> There is a strong cross-party openness in the Digitalrat